# Accumulation and rates with volume of concrete

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, calculus-of-variations

> $f(x)$ is the volume of concrete, in cubic meters, that has been added to a floor of a skyscraper after $x$ seconds of a $45$-second pour. Values of $r_f$ defined as $r_f(x)=2e^{-\frac{x}{15}}$ give the rate of change of $f$ in m$^3$/sec for all $0 \le x \le 45$ seconds.

First, I was asked to find the rate the concrete was being poured at $x=5.2$. I gave $1.4108$ and was marked correct. Then, I was asked to find the amount of concrete poured at $x=5.4$ given $f(5.2)=8.79$ m$^3$ of concrete. I took that value plus the slope of $f(5.2)$ times the change in $x$, giving me $0.282816$ which was also correct. Then I was asked to find the amount of concrete poured between $5.2$ and $6$ seconds. My answer was marked correct using $1.41408(0.8)$

But then I was given one last problem, "Revise your previous answer by estimating how much concrete is poured every $0.2$ seconds from $5.2$ to $6$ seconds"

I tried
$$1.41408(0.2)+1.41408(0.4)+1.41408(0.6)+1.41408(0.8)=2.82816$$

and was marked wrong. I realize I should not be using the same slope $y=1.41408$, and I also noticed I should not be multiplying by successive terms of $0.2$. I instead tried to say that variation is $m(0.2)$ where $m$ is $r_f(x)$. Basically $0.2r_f(5.4)+0.2r_f(5.6)+...+0.2r_f(6)$ After summing this up I got 1.37712 which seemed to make a lot more sense. But I was still marked wrong. What should I try at this point?

Comment: Have you tried taking the rate of change at beginning of each interval? Meaning the amount should be $0.2r_f(5.2)+0.2r_f(5.4)+0.2r_f(5.6)+0.2r_f(5.8)$

Comment: Can you please express what you have explained in words in form of equations? I cannot translate what you have done to obtain 0,2828216 as the answer for the second question..

Comment: @AlainRemillard After seeing your comment, I felt like asking this question. Do you agree with me, if I say $0.1r_f(5,2)+0.2r_f(5.4)+0.2r_f(5.6)+0,2r_f(5.8)+0.1r_f(6)$ might give a better estimate than the equation you have proposed?

Comment: @YNK, I used the fact that $y_{final}=y_{initial}+m\Delta x$

Comment: @YNK when webuse linear approximation, we usualy use the derivative at one point to approximate what happen after. This is why I suggest my approach. OP writing suggests it is from a web-based question with automatic answers.

Comment: @AlainRemillard Thanks for expressing your views on your and my suggestions. Actually, in this kind of situations, there are a few different ways to express the solution to the same problem. Here is one of them, which uses the derivatives at the midpoints of time intervals. $0.2r_f(5.3)+0.2r_f(5.5)+0.2r_f(5.7)+0.2r_f(5.9)$

Comment: @Lex_i Ok, I agree with the formula you gave in your comment. But, how did you get  0.282816 as $y_{final}$ when $y_{initial}=8.79$?

Comment: @Lex_i could you give us the source of this problem? Is it a program with automatic correction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make an answer of all that was discussed in the comments

First, OP hasn't provide the source of the problem, so there will be a few assumption I'll make. OP attempts suggest that it is a problem of linear approximation.  Since the rate of change function is integrable, I'll compare every answer with the "true" value obtain by integration.

**By integration**

The rate of change of $f$ is given by $r_f(x)=2e^{-\frac x{15}}$, $0\leq x\leq 45$. We could find the amount of concrete poured after $t$ second by
$$f(t)=\int_0^t r_f(x) dx = \int_0^t 2e^{-\frac x{15}} dx = 30\left(1-e^{-\frac t{15}}\right)$$
Note that $f(5.2)=8.788770921$ which is the value given by the problem.

> Find the amount on concrete poured after $5.4$ seconds.

$$f(5.4)=9.069710218\tag{1}$$
The amount that was poured between $5.2$ seconds and $5.4$ seconds is
$$f(5.4)-f(5.2)=0.280939297$$

> Find the amount of concrete poured between $5.2$ seconds and $6$ seconds.

$$f(6)-f(5.2) = 1.101627698\tag{2}$$

**By linear approximation**

The rate of change at $5.2$ is 
$$r_f(5.2)=2e^{-\frac{5.2}{15}}=1.414081939$$

> Find the amount on concrete poured after $5.4$ seconds knowing that $f(5.2)=8.79\text{ m}^3$

$$f(5.4) = f(5.2)+r_f(5.2)(5.4-5.2)=8.79+0.282816387\approx 9.072$$
which is less than $1\%$ away from the value computed in $(1)$.

> Find the amount of concrete poured between $5.2$ seconds and $6$ seconds.

$$f(6)-f(5.2) = r_f(5.2)(6-5.2) = 1.131265551$$
which is about $3\%$ over the value of $(2)$.

> Revise the amount of concrete poured between $5.2$ seconds and $6$ seconds by estimating how much concrete is poured every $0.2$ seconds.

*this is where I wanted to compare the different possibilities that were discussed in the comments*

OP suggest the following
$$0.2*r_f(5.4)+0.2*r_f(5.6)+0.2*r_f(5.8)+0.2*r_f(6)=1.094299834$$
Usualy we use the beginning of the interval for the approximation, and not the end. This will give us
$$0.2*r_f(5.2)+0.2*r_f(5.4)+0.2*r_f(5.6)+0.2*r_f(5.8)=1.108988203$$
@YNK suggested two other approachs. first by splitting the interval differently.
$$0.1*r_f(5.2)+0.2*r_f(5.4)+0.2*r_f(5.6)+0.2*r_f(5.8)+0.2*r_f(6)=1.101644018$$
Then by the middle of the interval
$$0.2*r_f(5.3)+0.2*r_f(5.5)+0.2*r_f(5.7)+0.2*r_f(5.9)=1.101619538$$